# Not able to make Jenkins perforce plugin to work with ssh

Tags: jenkins, perforce, jenkins-plugins

I am not quite familiar with Jenkins but for some reason I am not able to make the perforce plugin to work. I will list down the problem and what I have tried so as to get a better understanding.

Jenkins Version         - 1.561

Perforce Plugin Version - 1.3.27 (I have perforce path configured in Jenkins)

System                  - Ubuntu 10.04

**Problem:**

In the Source Code Management's *Project Details* section ( when you try to configure a new job ) I get "**Unable to check workspace against depot**" error.

```
P4PORT(hostname:port) - rsh:ssh -q -a -x -l p4ssh -q -x xxx.xxx.com /bin/true
Username              - ialok
Password              - N.A (Connection to SCM is via key authentication so left it blank)
Workspace(client)     - ialok_jenkins
```

I let Jenkins create workspace and manage its view by checking the checkbox for both *"Let Jenkins Create Workspace"* and *"Let Jenkins Manage Workspace View"*

Client View Type is a *View Map* with the following mapping:

//sandbox/srkamise/... //ialok_jenkins/srkamise/...

I have the keys loaded prior to starting jenkins and the jenkins process runs as my user (ialok)

```
~$ ps aux | grep jenkins
ialok    16608  0.0  0.0  14132   552 ?        Ss   11:08   0:00 /usr/bin/daemon --name=ialok --inherit --env=JENKINS_HOME=/var/lib/jenkins --output=/var/log/jenkins/jenkins.log --pidfile=/var/run/jenkins/jenkins.pid -- /usr/bin/java -Djava.awt.headless=true -jar /usr/share/jenkins/jenkins.war --webroot=/var/cache/jenkins/war --httpPort=8080 --ajp13Port=-1
ialok    16609  1.0 13.9 1448716 542156 ?      Sl   11:08   1:04 /usr/bin/java -Djava.awt.headless=true -jar /usr/share/jenkins/jenkins.war --webroot=/var/cache/jenkins/war --httpPort=8080 --ajp13Port=-1
```

Additionally, I used ***envInject*** plugin and *"Under Prepare an environment for the run"* I added *SSD_AGENT_PID*, *SSH_AUTH_SOCK*, *P4USER*, *P4PORT* environment parameters. (I did try without envInject but faced the same issue)

It looks like some authentication problem as I double checked the path to p4 executable along with the project mapping and addition of keys to my environment.

Here is the log file indicating a failed run:

```
Started by user anonymous
[EnvInject] - Loading node environment variables.
[EnvInject] - Preparing an environment for the build.
[EnvInject] - Keeping Jenkins system variables.
[EnvInject] - Keeping Jenkins build variables.
[EnvInject] - Injecting as environment variables the properties content 
P4CONFIG=.perforce
P4PORT=rsh:ssh -q -a -x -l p4ssh -q -x xxx.xxx.com /bin/true
P4USER=ialok
SSH_AGENT_PID=25752
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/keyring-7GAS75/ssh

[EnvInject] - Variables injected successfully.
[EnvInject] - Injecting contributions.
Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/fin/workspace
Using master perforce client: ialok_jenkins
[workspace] $ /usr/bin/p4 workspace -o ialok_jenkins
Changing P4 Client Root to: /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/fin/workspace
Changing P4 Client View from:


Changing P4 Client View to: 
  //sandbox/srkamise/... //ialok_jenkins/srkamise/...
Saving new client ialok_jenkins
[workspace] $ /usr/bin/p4 -s client -i
Caught exception communicating with perforce.  TCP receive failed. read: socket: Connection reset by peer
For Command: /usr/bin/p4 -s client -i 
With Data:
===================
Client: ialok_jenkins
Description: 
Root: /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/fin/workspace
Options: noallwrite clobber nocompress unlocked nomodtime rmdir
LineEnd: local
View:
  //sandbox/srkamise/... //ialok_jenkins/srkamise/...


===================
com.tek42.perforce.PerforceException:  TCP receive failed. read: socket: Connection reset by peer
For Command: /usr/bin/p4 -s client -i 
With Data:
===================
Client: ialok_jenkins
Description: 
Root: /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/fin/workspace
Options: noallwrite clobber nocompress unlocked nomodtime rmdir
LineEnd: local
View:
  //sandbox/srkamise/... //ialok_jenkins/srkamise/...


===================

    at com.tek42.perforce.parse.AbstractPerforceTemplate.saveToPerforce(AbstractPerforceTemplate.java:270)
    at com.tek42.perforce.parse.Workspaces.saveWorkspace(Workspaces.java:77)
    at hudson.plugins.perforce.PerforceSCM.saveWorkspaceIfDirty(PerforceSCM.java:1787)
    at hudson.plugins.perforce.PerforceSCM.checkout(PerforceSCM.java:895)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1251)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:604)
    at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:513)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1709)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:231)
ERROR: Unable to communicate with perforce.  TCP receive failed. read: socket: Connection reset by peer
For Command: /usr/bin/p4 -s client -i 
With Data:
===================
Client: ialok_jenkins
Description: 
Root: /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/fin/workspace
Options: noallwrite clobber nocompress unlocked nomodtime rmdir
LineEnd: local
View:
  //sandbox/srkamise/... //ialok_jenkins/srkamise/...


===================

Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: Try setting up the view yourself and not letting Jenkins control it. It looks like the tek42 wrapper + an rsh port + reading STDIN (the -i commands) == pain. If you manage the client yourself it won't need to run the commands with the -i flag at all.

Answer (score 1):

The P4PORT typically is of the form 'hostname.port'. Examples would be:

```
workshop.perforce.com:1666

myserver.mycompany.net:2500
```

Here's some docs: http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/P4PORT.html

Comment: Few links document how to make a connection to perforce using rsh. Seems like a hack but then I don't have any control over the scm here.

[link1](http://public.perforce.com/guest/tony_smith/perforce/p4u/main/README)

[link2](http://00photo.co.uk/paul/?p=15)